# How do I add a second ItemCollection (bindable) to a TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeviewitem

I need to get a second `ItemCollection` to a `TreeViewItem` in WPF. To do that, I want to make a custom `TreeViewItem` (inherits the normal `TreeViewItem`) and add the needed Properties hardcoded with C#. What are the steps to do that?

Why do I need this? I am trying to make a `FlowChartEditor` for an existing WPF program (with a existing `TreeView`).

For my `if` element, I need a true and a false collection to be bindable. It should look like this afterwards:

[image: 'If' element diagram]

I made a LoopItem for example like this:

```
public class LoopItem : TreeViewItem
{
    [Bindable(false)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public bool HasFooter
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasFooterProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(HasFooterProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasFooterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HasFooter",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(LoopItem),
            new PropertyMetadata(false
        );

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Bindable(true)]
    public object Footer
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(FooterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FooterProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Footer",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(LoopItem),
            new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );
}
```

Now I was able to bind not only a header, but also a footer. After writing my own style in XAML I have a result like this:

[image: Loop element diagram]

The arrows are drawn on a `Canvas`, which is used as a `ItemsPanel` on the `TreeView`. To be clear, this is the view I wanted to get. The **only question** is how to make it that way for an `if`.

So which properties do I need for an `if` item like in the first image? Somebody done that before?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that using TreeView is a good idea here. I would suggest creating your own panel that bind to your flow chart model. You can't show loops on TreeView in any other way than repeating the structure with infinite depth. Also, for flowcharts, I think adding things like panning, zooming etc should be implemented and doing so with TreeView will be VERY hard

Comment: I am drawing the arrows on a custom canvas which is used as the ItemsPanel for the TreeView. Getting this, was not the big problem. What i didn't get yet, is the If-TreeViewItem having two seperate ItemCollections.

Comment: If you already figured out drawing arrows on Canvas how I suggested before, just do the same with the nodes - most of your problems will dissapear. TreeView is prolematic enough with standard uses (like Hover on nodes propagating to the parent nodes for no apparent reason). Go full on Canvas, then you will be able to easily add dragging the nodes etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to modify the `TreeViewItem`. It's about how your data structures are designed. You need to categorize or specialize your data models (or nodes) e.g.:

- a conditional node, that must contain two child nodes, which are representing each branch.
- a common expression node, which only has a single child node.
- a junction node (join of multiple parent nodes), that has one child but multiple parents (collection of
  nodes).
- a loop node, that has a child node (the body) and additional attributes, like a set of loop conditions
- an iteration node, that might also have a child node (the body) and attributes, like a set of iteration conditions

If you decide to stay with the `TreeView`, I don't recommend this, then you would use a `HierachicalDataTemplate` to design the appearance of a `TreeView`.

But it will be more flexible to leave the `TreeView` alone and draw the whole tree instead using node controls. You can convert from tree data model representation (using specialized node model classes) to visual representation (and vice versa) by traversing the tree data model and add corresponding visual node objects to the drawing canvas (a `Control` that you can template and style too, to give them the desired look). When you let these controls extend the `Thumb` control, it will be very easy to add dragging to the visual nodes.

The following code is a simple (and ugly) example to show how to connect two objects (of type `Node`) by pressing and holding *Ctrl-Key* and drawing a line between them. There are two `Node` objects, that are already created and positioned on the canvas. Later they should be either dragged to the canvas from a pool of node objects or automatically drawn to the canvas by converting the graph to visual and connected `Node` objects. Since `Node`extends `Thumb` you are able to drag the `Node` controls across the `DrawingArea`:

**XAML usage example**

```
<local:DrawingArea Focusable="True">
    <local:DrawingArea.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Line">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </local:DrawingArea.Resources>
    <local:Node CurrentPosition="0, 0" />
    <local:Node CurrentPosition="150, 150" />      
</local:DrawingArea>
```

**The `Node` drawing object. It extends `Thumb` to make it support dragging**

```
class Node : Thumb
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentPositionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "CurrentPosition",
    typeof(Point),
    typeof(Node),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(Point), OnCurrentPositionChanged));

  public Point CurrentPosition { get { return (Point) GetValue(Node.CurrentPositionProperty); } set { SetValue(Node.CurrentPositionProperty, value); } }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildNodesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ChildNodes",
    typeof(ObservableCollection<Node>),
    typeof(Node),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<Node>)));

  public ObservableCollection<Node> ChildNodes { get { return (ObservableCollection<Node>) GetValue(Node.ChildNodesProperty); } set { SetValue(Node.ChildNodesProperty, value); } }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty DrawingAreaProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "DrawingArea",
    typeof(DrawingArea),
    typeof(Node),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(DrawingArea)));

  public DrawingArea DrawingArea { get { return (DrawingArea) GetValue(Node.DrawingAreaProperty); } set { SetValue(Node.DrawingAreaProperty, value); } }

  static Node()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Node), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Node)));
  }

  public Node()
  {
    this.DragDelta += MoveOnDragStarted;
    Canvas.SetLeft(this, this.CurrentPosition.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(this, this.CurrentPosition.Y);
  }

  private static void OnCurrentPositionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var _this = d as Node;
    Canvas.SetLeft(_this, _this.CurrentPosition.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(_this, _this.CurrentPosition.Y);
  }

  private void MoveOnDragStarted(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs dragDeltaEventArgs)
  {
    if (this.DrawingArea.IsDrawing)
    {
      return;
    }

    this.CurrentPosition = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(this) + dragDeltaEventArgs.HorizontalChange, Canvas.GetTop(this) + dragDeltaEventArgs.VerticalChange);
  }
}
```

**The `Node` style. Add this to the `ResourceDictionary` of *Generic.xaml* file**

```
<Style TargetType="local:Node">
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
  <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True"/>
  <Setter Property="DrawingArea" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Canvas}}"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Node">
        <Border Background="Red"></Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

**The `DrawingArea` which is an extended `Canvas` that does the line drawing (exposing the editor features)**

```
class DrawingArea : Canvas
{
  static DrawingArea()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DrawingArea), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DrawingArea)));
  }

  public DrawingArea()
  {
    this.TemporaryDrawingLine = new Line();
  }

  #region Overrides of UIElement

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
    if (e.Key.HasFlag(Key.LeftCtrl) || e.Key.HasFlag(Key.RightCtrl))
    {
      this.IsDrawing = true;
    }
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void OnPreviewKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
    if (e.Key.HasFlag(Key.LeftCtrl) || e.Key.HasFlag(Key.RightCtrl))
    {
      this.IsDrawing = false;
      this.Children.Remove(this.TemporaryDrawingLine);
    }
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    if (!this.IsDrawing)
    {
      return;
    }

    if (!(e.Source is Node linkedItem))
    {
      return;
    }

    this.StartObject = linkedItem;
    this.TemporaryDrawingLine = new Line()
    {
      X1 = this.StartObject.CurrentPosition.X, Y1 = this.StartObject.CurrentPosition.Y,
      X2 = e.GetPosition(this).X, Y2 = e.GetPosition(this).Y,
      StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection() { 5, 1, 1, 1}
    };
    this.Children.Add(this.TemporaryDrawingLine);
  }


  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    Focus();
    if (!this.IsDrawing)
    {
      return;
    }

    this.TemporaryDrawingLine.X2 = e.GetPosition(this).X;
    this.TemporaryDrawingLine.Y2 = e.GetPosition(this).Y ;
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
    if (!this.IsDrawing)
    {
      return;
    }

    if (!(e.Source is Node linkedItem))
    {
      this.Children.Remove(this.TemporaryDrawingLine);
      this.IsDrawing = false;
      return;
    }

    e.Handled = true;
    this.Children.Remove(this.TemporaryDrawingLine);
    var line = new Line();
    var x1Binding = new Binding("CurrentPosition.X") {Source = this.StartObject};
    var y1Binding = new Binding("CurrentPosition.Y") { Source = this.StartObject };
    line.SetBinding(Line.X1Property, x1Binding);
    line.SetBinding(Line.Y1Property, y1Binding);

    this.EndObject = linkedItem;
    var x2Binding = new Binding("CurrentPosition.X") { Source = this.EndObject };
    var y2Binding = new Binding("CurrentPosition.Y") { Source = this.EndObject };
    line.SetBinding(Line.X2Property, x2Binding);
    line.SetBinding(Line.Y2Property, y2Binding);
    this.Children.Add(line);
    this.IsDrawing = false;
  }

  public bool IsDrawing { get; set; }

  private Node EndObject { get; set; }  
  private Node StartObject { get; set; }  
  private Line TemporaryDrawingLine { get; set; }    

  #endregion
}
```